# Exception class not found in Laravel

Tags: php, exception, namespaces

When I use this code in Laravel framework:

```
throw new Exception("failed");
```

it throws this error:

> FatalErrorException in MyController.php line 178:
>   Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Exception' not found

Does anybody know how can I `use` *(`include`)* that `Exception` class to my controller? Where is actually it?

Comment: It's `\Exception`, your code is namespaced

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Throw the exception using the following code.

```
throw new \Exception("failed");
```

Otherwise, import the class before using.

```
use Exception;
```

Comment: how the pro developers handle throws in laravel?